# Composer takes forever to download even with hirak/prestissimo?

Tags: php, composer-php

Why does `composer create-project` take forever to download and create project?

I have tried:

Slim:

```
$ composer create-project slim/slim-skeleton slim-app
```

Laravel:

```
$ composer create-project laravel/laravel lavavel-app"5.0.*" --prefer-dist
```

It is just extremely slow:

```
Installing slim/slim-skeleton (3.1.2)
  - Installing slim/slim-skeleton (3.1.2) Downloading: 100%         
Created project in mr-simon-cohen-slim
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
(it just stuck here...)
```

Any ideas?

I'm on Kubuntu 16.10.

**EDIT:**

After installing `hirak/prestissimo`, I get this error:

```
$ composer create-project slim/slim-skeleton slim-app

Cannot create cache directory /home/tealou/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
Cannot create cache directory /home/tealou/.composer/cache/files/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
Cannot create cache directory /home/tealou/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
Cannot create cache directory /home/tealou/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
(it stuck here forever now)
```

During installing `hirak/prestissimo`, I get this error:

```
$ composer global require "hirak/prestissimo:^0.3"

Changed current directory to /home/teelou/.composer


  [ErrorException]                                                              
  file_put_contents(./composer.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

So i used sudo:

```
$ sudo composer global require "hirak/prestissimo:^0.3"
[sudo] password for teelou: 
Changed current directory to /home/teelou/.composer
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
./composer.json has been created
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing hirak/prestissimo (0.3.5) Downloading: 100%         
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

What can I do to fix this mess now?

**EDIT 2:**

I got it fixed by:

```
$ sudo chmod -R 777 /home/teelou/.composer/
```

But `hirak/prestissimo` **does not** help in speeding up the download at all. It is still very slow.

Comment: You should really try this out https://github.com/hirak/prestissimo

Comment: How much RAM has your machine installed? Composer uses plenty of it, usually in the range of 1GB at least, usually more. Low memory machines will simply write to the swap file like crazy and look like they stalled, because they'd need a thousand times longer to get anything done.

Comment: @Sven I have 16 RAM in my machine. I am on Ubuntu 16.10.

Comment: Sound like plenty of RAM. Any details from `top` when the command is running?

Comment: @Sven yes it should have more than enough. what **command** should i run and then get the `top`?

Comment: The original composer command without that parallel download plugin. You'd likely have to remove it before starting, otherwise it will be active and affect results.